# Ошибка в router [Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException]

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет, проект на Laravel 5.3. Возникает следующая ошибка при вводе php artisan route:list https://c2n.me/3QZ2o9v . Пробую убрать Route::group(['middleware'.... роутеры появляются. А так админ часть работает нормально.

```
    <?php

Route::resource('/', 'IndexController', [
    'only' => ['index'],
    'names' => [
        'index' => 'home'
    ]
]);

Route::resource('catalog', 'CatalogController', [
    'parameters' => [
        'catalog' => 'alias'
    ]
]);

Route::get('catalog/cat/{cat_alias?}', [
    'uses' => 'CatalogController@index', 'as' => 'catalogCat'
]);

Route::resource('articles', 'ArticlesController', [
    'parameters' => [
        'articles' => 'alias'
    ]
]);

Route::get('articles/cat/{cat_alias?}', [
    'uses' => 'ArticlesController@index', 'as' => 'articlesCat'
])->where('cat_alias', '[\w-]+');

Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/contacts', ['uses' => 'ContactsController@index', 'as' => 'contacts']);

Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/order', ['uses' => 'OrderController@index', 'as' => 'order']);

Route::get('find', 'SearchController@find');

Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/price', ['uses' => 'PriceController@index', 'as' => 'price']);

Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/map', ['uses' => 'MapController@index', 'as' => 'map']);

Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/careers', ['uses' => 'CareersController@index', 'as' => 'careers']);


Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');

Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');

Route::get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function () {

    Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'IndexController@index', 'as' => 'adminIndex']);

    Route::resource('/articles', 'ArticlesController');

    Route::resource('/catalog', 'CatalogController');

    Route::resource('/permissions', 'PermissionsController');

    Route::resource('/users', 'UsersController');

    Route::resource('/pages', 'PagesController');

    Route::resource('/categories', 'CategoriesController');

    Route::resource('/categories_news', 'CategoriesNewsController');

    Route::resource('/sliders', 'SlidersController');

    Route::resource('/measurements', 'MeasurementsController');

    Route::resource('/prices', 'PricesController');

    Route::resource('/upload', 'UploadController@destroy');

});
```

Comment: Ну а ты пробовал методом сперва все убрать и по одной добавлять и искать где ошибка ) может у тебя какой контроллер назван не верно

Comment: Пробовал конечно ). При добавлении любого из этих существующих сразу возникает эта ошибка.

Comment: А это точно все методы ? Там по-моему правило, что не должно быт анонимных методов, возможно он group методо таковым считает, но я тут не уверен

Comment: Слушай ну а попробуй там сперва `composer dump-autuload` сделать

Comment: https://c2n.me/3QZ5c6G

Comment: Нет это не все методы. Выше тоже имеется только выше все работает при вводе этой команды.

Comment: Ну а если ты без префикса выставляешь то все норм ?

Comment: а попробуй ради интереса ['auth'], хотя вряд ли

Comment: К сожалению тоже не помогло, убрал по одному и оба 'middleware' => 'auth', 'prefix' => 'admin' ошибка та же. Если убираю 'prefix' => 'admin' то уже и при запросе в браузере 404.

Comment: Не короче просто у вас ве же где то косяк с каким то методом, пробуй сперва без группы composer dump-autuload, php artisan clear-compiled и дальше добавляй по одному и смотри

Comment: Да попробую так, отпишусь завтра, если найду причину, спасибо.

Comment: Добрый вечер, нашел проблему. Почему то не правильно работает наследование. Попробую объяснить у меня есть AdminController 
 это кастомный базовый контроллер для остальных классов который тоже наследуется от Controller. В нем описаны базовые функции чтобы не повторялись articles, catalog, permissions и т.д.

Comment: https://c2n.me/3R0Ipu6

Comment: Если же наследовать не от AdminController, а от Controller то маршрутизация работает прекрасно.

Comment: Ну тут нужно смотреть что у тебя в AdminController и в контроллер ? если ты что-то переопределяешь в конструкторе или добавляешь middleware

Comment: Спасибо  Orange_shadow! Да действительно в конструкторе я написал: https://c2n.me/3R1fF1F abort(403); из-за него доступ далее был запрещен. Так как консоль не может быть авторизированной ) в следствие чего возникала ошибка.

Answer (score -1):

Ошибку нашёл в классе AdminController который наследуется от Controller. Там описан конструктор следующего содержания:

```
public function __construct() {

    $this->user = Auth::user();

    if(!$this->user) {
        abort(403);
    }
}
```

Из за abort(403) и возникала ошибка, спасибо Orange_shadow.

Comment: Почитайте пожалуйста документацию, вы в корне неправильно используете мидлвар. Зачем делать проверки в контроллере, если их необходимо делать промежуточно через мидлвар, ограничивая доступ на этапе роута. Научитесь писать собственные проверки в middleware.

Comment: Спасибо за правильное направление, на момент написания вопроса я только изучал laravel.